# Spivak - introducing the derivative to the integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Spivak writes that if a function $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, we can define a new function $F:[a,b] \to \Bbb{R}$ by the rule
\begin{align}
F(x) := \int_a^x f \equiv \int_a^x f(t) \, dt
\end{align}
(where I use "$\equiv$" to mean "same thing expressed in different notation").

He writes that this depends on a previous theorem, one which essentially stated that the integral of a function $f$ on $[a,b]$ could be broken up into two separate intervals, and vice versa, provided $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.

The first part -- about "introducing" the derivative to the integral -- stumped me, and I haven't been able to find any insightful connection between the theorem and the equality. Could someone please provide some guidance or clarify how or why the derivative appeared?

On a side note, I suspect this newly defined function may also be related to the theorem immediately preceding it (a picture of the whole page has been pasted below), though beyond the "suppose now," I don't see how.

[image]

Comment: Downvoter care to share?

Comment: It's probably because you didn't type it up with Mathjax and proper formatting. I have edited it accordingly; check to see if it is what you had intended.

Comment: also, I don't see any derivatives introduced here, so could you clarify what you mean. From what I recall, the FTC comes in the next chapter.

Comment: I think you just need to keep going.  It'll be a couple more pages before Spivak makes the connection you're looking for.  All that's happened here is that he's made a definition.  The next few theorems use the definition.

Comment: Have you gone through the first part of the fundamental theorem of calculus including the definition of the area function which is defined as an integral that represents area beneath a curve?

Comment: @peek-a-boo thank you for the formatting - it is what I intended and it looks readable now! Also, the statement referred to in the question is after the proof of theorem seven but before the statement of theorem eight. I know it's not a "proper" derivative (insofar as you differentiate a function with respect to some variable) but I wasn't sure how or why it (the "dt") appeared in the text. This was the first appearance of a "derivative" (or whatever I mean by this) anywhere in the chapter.

Comment: @B.Goddard thank you - I'll keep going. I was just a bit hesitant about continuing without actually understanding the definition.

Comment: @Axion004 the fundamental theorem of calculus actually hasn't been introduced yet.

Comment: https://notendur.hi.is/mbh6/html/_downloads/Calculus%20-%20Michael%20Spivak.pdf

Comment: @Axion004 I've linked a copy of the book. Spivak introduces the integral in a very interesting way. The chapter on integrals (chapter 13) is almost all about partitions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your latest comment, here's my answer: The presence of $dt$ in the integral is not meant to suggest any sort of derivative/differentiation. At the level you are studying, you should just take the notation $\int_a^x f(t)\, dt$ as just that - a piece of notation. This notation has been around for hundreds of years, and at times it is very handy, which is why we keep it around.

(This is why in my edit, I used the symbol "$\equiv$" and explicitly wrote that it means the same thing as $\int_a^x f$, just written differently)

In this book, Spivak more often uses the notation $\int_a^b f$ instead, and as he explains in the beginning of the chapter, this is equal to a certain real number which you calculate by taking the sup/inf of lower/upper sums. I suggest you **CAREFULLY** read through pages 261 and 262 of his book again, where he explains how to interpret the notation (I think his choice of words in explaining things is very clear, so pay close attention to it :).

Anyway, the purpose of the remark which Spivak made is to explain why the new function being defined, $F$, is actually well-defined (i.e why it makes sense from a logical perspective). What are we doing with the new function $F$? Well, we start by assuming $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. Then, we pick any $x \in [a,b]$, and **we wish to define**
\begin{align}
F(x) = \int_a^x f.
\end{align}
However, before we make such a definition, we need to ask ourselves: "does this make sense?" Look at what is on the RHS, we have the integral $\int_a^x f$, so we need to verify that this **number actually exists**! This is where Theorem 4 comes in:

> Theorem $4 \implies$ for any $x \in [a,b]$, $f$ is integrable on $[a,x]$ (i.e the **real number** $\int_a^x f$ **exists**).

It is because of this highlighted implication that we can define the function $F$ on $[a,b]$, and everything is logical (all the things actually exist).

Comment: Wow, thank you. I just went back to the pages you suggested - that was blindingly obvious! I have no idea how I didn't see that before!

Comment: @Aaron Also, to really understand theorem 8 from a deeper level, I suggest that you take a look at chapter $11$ problem $34$, where Spivak introduces the notion of "$f$ is Lipschitz continuous of order $\alpha$ on an interval $I$". Once you understand the basic definitions of Lipschitz continuity, you can prove the following:$$ \text{ $F$ is Lipschitz continuous of order $1$ on $[a,b]$} \implies \text{ $F$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$} \implies \text{$F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$} $$

Comment: The purpose of theorem $13$-$8$ is to show you that if $f$ is integrable , then the integrated function $F$ is more "well behaved". Spivak claims that $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, but his proof actually shows a much stronger result, namely: $F$ is Lipschitz continuous of order $1$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: @Aaron: Don't feel bad for not immediately understanding this. Continue reading the textbook slowly and write out theorems and definitions in your own words.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for the observations! I'll mull them over - on the surface, they seem as if they will provide greater importance to the concepts.

Comment: @Axion004 Thanks and great suggestion - I'll do that!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can think of $dt$ as more than just a "piece of notation".

First of all, think about integration as infinite summation.  An integration is merely the sum of an infinite number of infinitely small values.

Areas are found by breaking up a shape into infinitely small boxes, and then adding them up.  So, if you have the function $f(t)$, and you want to know the infinitely small area *at* $t = t_0$, then the area itself is width ($dt$ - an infinitely-small width) times the height of the function ($f(t)$).  Put together, this is written $f(t)\,dt$.

If we want to add up *all* the areas, we sum them.  But, since there are an infinite number of them, we use an integral.  Therefore, the area under the curve is the sum of all of the tiny areas, or $$\int f(t)\,dt$$

So, perhaps a better way of writing this would be to say, "if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then if we want to define a function for giving us the area under the curve of $f(t)$ from $a$ to some other value, we can see that this would be done by finding the infinitely small area at each point along the interval, and then summing them all up.  The infinitely small area at each point will be given by $f(t)\,dt$, and they can be summed from $a$ to $x$ using $$\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$$  Therefore, we can define $F(x)$ to be equivalent to this function."

A summary of looking at integrals this way can be found in [Simplifying and Refactoring Introductory Calculus](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.03459)